# connecting azure web app to azure cosmos db

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to replicate the tutorial for connecting an azure web app (based on express) to azure cosmos db using mongoose [Using Mongoose Framework with Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-mongoose)

However I am not able  to connect to my database named **testdb**. I have a *server.js* file where I put all the code for simplicity and an *.env* file which contains the connection string and the name of the database as described in the tutorial.

I have inserted the code contained by *server.js*, below.  The code is based on the one in the tutorial, just that I added the pug template engine, for the app, with the intention that once i create a collection I may get info from it and integrated with the pug template.

The pug file is displayed by the app but no collection is created in the database and I do not know where is the problem.

One issue that seems striking in the tutorial is that the connection string of the azure cosmos db already contains "*?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb*" and i do not understand why the tutorial is appending it again when connecting to database. I have removed from the connection string saved in the .env file that part but nothing happens either. I have also encoded the special character in the connection string like (==, @, ? or /).

Seems to me that I cannot form correctly the connection string, but I do not know how to solve this issue. What is the correct pattern for the connection string when you are trying to create a collection in an empty database? There should be slashes between connection string and db name and between db name and the query?

Another question is related to the fact that the code from the tutorial is containing calls of console.log function for displaying message on the console. My question is, on which console that messages are supposed to be displayed, on the browser console or on the node console? In the browser there are not displayed any messages.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Many thanks!

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const env = require('dotenv').load();    //Use the .env file to load the variables

const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5050; //normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5050');
app.set('port', port);
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

mongoose.connect(process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNSTR+process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME+"?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"); //Creates a new DB, if it doesn't already exist
//mongoose.connect(dbc);
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
console.log("Connected to DB");
});

const cities = mongoose.model('cities', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    country: String
}));

const city = new cities({
 name: "Paris",
 country: "France"
});

city.save( function (err, savedCity) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(savedCity));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        panelTitle: "Azure CosmosDB Test",  
        panelBody:"Testing how to access Azure ComsosDB",
    });
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently completed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-mongodb-react) that walks you through building an Express-based server that uses Mongoose to connect to Cosmos DB. You can see the end result here:
https://github.com/ydogandjiev/react-cosmosdb

A couple of issues I ran into were:

1. I had to use the following syntax to connect to the database (or escape the password string):

   ```
   mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${env.user}.documents.azure.com:${env.port}/?        ssl=true`, {
     auth: {
       user: env.user,
       password: env.password
     }
   });
   ```
2. Using the latest version of the Mongo client requires you to enable the preview features on your CosmosDB instance:
   [image: CosmosDB Preview Features]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yuri! I have used your code and eventually succeeded to create a collection (with one document) couple of times. I have also enabled the preview features. However if i delete the collection and try to create it again does not work immediately. It seems that my successful attempts are completely random.

Comment: If I run npm start in kudu console I receive an _MongoError: Authentication Failed message_

Comment: I have solved it after all, based on your code above. I have used strings for the uri, user and password between back-ticks(`). I do not escaped the special character and works just fine. Actually when i have escaped the == from the password I got an error message. Thanks for your suggestions. The earlier randomness could be explained by the fact that I did not used the kudu console to kill the node process running after I have made changes to the code. Therefore probably the server used the old code, although i would have expected for azure to have a process manager of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

`mongoose.connect` wants the string to have a `/DBNAME` between the network part of the conn str and the options part.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');
```

Take the connection string from the CosmosDB portal and insert the dbname with a slash `/dbname` before the `?ssl=true...`

You can do this by setting `COSMOSDB_CONNSTR` to be just the part of the connection string up until but not including the `?` and making sure it ends with a `/`

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments to Yuri Doganjiev answer, his code and the suggestion of enabling the preview features on the dashboard of azure cosmos db account resulted in succeeding in connecting to azure cosmosdb and create collection and querying the database. The version of *mongoose* used by me is *5.0.14*.

The actual connection code used is below, where *[host]*, *[port]*, *[username]* and *[password]* are the value mentioned in connection string tab on azure dashboard. The *[dbname]* is the name of the database to which wish to connect.I did not escaped any special characters like (/, =, ?).Actually when I tried to escape some of them I got error messages.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://[host]:[port]/[dbname]?ssl=true`, {
    auth: {
      user: `[username]`,
      password: `[password]`
    }
  })
  .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

The problem for me was that I was not able to receive any error messages besides the generic one like 404 - not found or 500 - internal error problem.

Only after I have run **npm start** in the kudu console under the root directory of the app I started to receive meaningful error messages which helped me to identify were the problem is. Furthermore the *console.log* function used in the app code printed its message in the kudu console, showing if the connection is successful or displaying the newly inserted objects in the collection.

Another issue that I have encountered is that you cannot end the node process in kudu console by *Ctrl + C*. The only way to end the process that I found is the process explorer in kudu that is displaying the running processes and lets you kill them. So even when I have made changes to the code, such changes where not reflected in the browser immediately as the old node process (using the old code) was still running.

I do not know what kind of process manager uses Azure Web App but not always changes in the code are reflected in the browser.

Comment: for future reference about process in kudu, you have a menu called "Process explorer" the you will find a list of process kudu, clicking in the proipierties... button on each if the process will let you kill it, the npm start will spawn a process child of "cmd.exe" in the case you start from cmd console option, in this way you can stop the webapp, go to console and start npm start to see the log but there are more elegant methods like this https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/07/debug-nodejs-applications-in-windows.html